# Objective-c: How can I get Class instance in class method

Tags: objective-c, class-method

I have 2 classes, Parent and Child, and Parent has a class method named func.
Now I want to get Class instance in func method to distinguish which class is caller.

```
@interface Parent : NSObject
+ (void)func;
@end

@implementation Parent

+ (void)func {
    Class *class = howToGetClass();
    NSLog(@"%@ call func", class);
}

@end

@interface Child : Parent
@end

int main() {
    [Child func];    // call func from Child
}
```

Is there any way to get class instance (or class name) in class method?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you just want to log it/get it as a Class, you just need `self`.  Thats it.  So like

```
+ (void)func {
    Class class = self;
    NSLog(@"%@ call func", class);
}
```

or

```
+ (void)func {
    NSLog(@"%@ call func", self);
}
```

also, if you want to get the name as an NSString, NSStringFromClass(self) has you covered.  (As a char *, class_getName(self) is what you're looking for)

Comment: I'm trying to add some utility methods(like all() in django) to NSManagedObject. So I need to distinguish the caller.
Using 'self' is what I wanted to know! Thanks!

Comment: It wasn't me who down voted, but I just checked, and in a class method

    self==[self class]

Just saw this had been said in another comment, but to clarify, they're IDENTICAL, in a class method at least.

So you were right, and so was I

Comment: Class *class = self; is wrong. Remove *. Correct syntax is: Class class = self;

Answer (score 3):

To get the current class object, you should be able to do:

```
[self class];
```

As self will refer to the class instance, because it's a class method. Class is a method defined in NSObject, which returns the class for the object.

Edited to avoid confusion...

Comment: To clarify, this returns the `Class` object of your class, not only the *name* as is implied by the answer.

Comment: actually, [self class] is the same as self in a class method.  The docs (ok fine the GNUStep docs) actually say it is implemented just with 'return self;'.  It only exists for passing classes as arguments, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107213/why-do-we-have-to-do-myclass-class-in-objective-c

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know that 'self' can be used in class method!

Comment: [someInstance class] is best. No compiler warning. Says what it is. Doesn't depend on implementation quirks.

Comment: eh? Obviously, in a class method, `self` refers to the class. That's object orientation. No implementation quirk. In fact, the one implementation quirk is that `class` returns the class when called on a class object; it should return the class's class, but since ObjC has no metaclasses, it doesn't matter, but the only reason it exists is so that `[MyClass class]` returns the `MyClass` class. **That** is the language quirk, not `self` referring to the class in a class method.