# Is there a way to deduce the type of Class in which a Class method is being executed, without instantiating an object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective-c: How can I get Class instance in class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125000/objective-c-how-can-i-get-class-instance-in-class-method)

Title pretty much sums it up.

Let's say I have

```
+ (void) someMethod
{
    [NSString stringWithFormat@"Calling Class: %@", ???];
}
```

I want to be able to fill in ??? with the class that the class belongs to WITHOUT having to instantiate an object.

I promise I have a good reason for wanting to do this.

Comment: Yup. You nailed it. Thanks for the link... was a hard one to search for.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the class can be found by [NSObject's className](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/className) or if you want the class itself [NSObject's class](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/class)