# Comparing of 'Class' with other 'Class' in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

Does a comparable function to '**isKindOfClass:**' exist for comparing a 'Class' to another (i.e. without constructing an instance of either class). For example, given:

```
Class class = NSClassFromString(@"NSNumber");

[NSNumber isKindOfClass:class]; // YES
[NSString isKindOfClass:class]; // NO
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[`+ (BOOL)isSubclassOfClass:(Class)aClass`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/isSubclassOfClass:)

and

```
Class theClass = NSClassFromString(@"NSNumber");

if ([NSNumber class] == theClass) {
    // YES
}
```

There is never more than 1 instance of a class, that's why `==` is the operator you're looking for.

Comment: Hi Georg. The Second example results in a compile error "Expected expression before 'NSNumber'", however the first one works! Do you know if it is possible to limit to not include subclasses? Thanks!

Comment: the if statement should be `if ([NSNumber class] == class)`.  For more info, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107213

Comment: @Kevin: Fixed that, I should have checked it before. Sorry.

Comment: @Dave: Thanks, that other question is really interesting.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, you can do:

```
[NSNumber isSubclassOfClass:class]; //YES
[NSString isSubclassOfClass:class]; //NO
```

These are class methods on `NSObject`.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Is it possible to limit to not include subclasses? Thanks.

Comment: @Kevin as @Georg points out, you can do: `[NSNumber class] == class`