# iOS pass selector and target for class methods

Tags: ios, selector, target, class-method

I am trying to use https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD in my iOS project. This has a specific method that I am trying to use, below:

```
/** 
 * Shows the HUD while a background task is executing in a new thread, then hides the HUD.
 *
 * This method also takes care of NSAutoreleasePools so your method does not have to be concerned with setting up a
 * pool.
 *
 * @param method The method to be executed while the HUD is shown. This method will be executed in a new thread.
 * @param target The object that the target method belongs to.
 * @param object An optional object to be passed to the method.
 * @param animated If set to YES the HUD will disappear using the current animationType. If set to NO the HUD will not use
 * animations while disappearing.
 */
- (void)showWhileExecuting:(SEL)method onTarget:(id)target withObject:(id)object animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

I would like to call a class/static method from a Singleton in the background here. What do I pass as the target? I've tried just giving the class name and it gives me an error.

Comment: Try `[Singleton class]`. [Here's why.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107213/why-do-we-have-to-do-myclass-class-in-objective-c)